# Stream - Nested Collection - Convert to Map

Tags: java-8, java-stream, nested-loops

Let's say i have 2 classes.

**Course Class**

```
public class Course {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Course> courses;
}
```

I have `List<Student>` and each `Student` is enrolled in multiple courses.

I need to filter out results using Java 8 stream API's as following.

```
Map<courseId, List<Student>>
```

I have tried below, but no success:

**1st Approach**

```
Map<Integer, List<Student>> courseStudentMap = studentList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        student -> student.getCourses().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Course::getId))));
```

**2nd Approach**

```
Map<Integer, List<Student>> courseStudentMap = studentList.stream()
    .filter(student -> student.getCourses().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Course::getId, Collectors.mapping(Student::student, Collectors.toList()))));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Map<Integer, List<Student>> result = studentsList
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getCourses().stream().map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, y.getId())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work (where `SimpleEntry` is a class that implements `Map.Entry<Integer,Student>`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Student>> courseStudentMap =
    studentList.stream()
               .flatMap(s -> s.getCourses()
                              .stream()
                              .map(c -> new SimpleEntry<>(c.getId(),s)))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                           Collectors.toList())));
```

The idea is to first transform the `Stream<Student>` to a `Stream` of all the pairs of course IDs and `Student`s. Once you got that `Stream`, you can use `groupingBy` to obtain the desired output `Map`.

Comment: Upvote for the explanation of the answer and the answer :)